# change the <header> </ header> tag in a specific prestashop

Tags: header, prestashop

Please, how can I change the   tag of a specific page in prestashop (not in the whole site : not in header.tpl)?
 I am on PS 1.6 
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use something like in the `header.tpl`:

`{if $page_name == 'my-account'}<meta name="WHATEVER" content="WHATEVER" />{/if}`.

You can find the `$page_name` by looking at the `<id>` tag on the `<body>` of that specific page. Be careful though some of the `$page_name` are not unique, for products for example it will always be `product`, no matter what the specific product is.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
{if isset($page_name) && $page_name == 'YOUR PAGE'} NEW CODE {/if}
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the solution I tried, but sometimes it doesn't work, in fact there are some pages with same $ page_name, exp: category or product.

Comment: And add : {if isset($body_classes) && $body_classes|@count} {implode value=$body_classes separator=' '}{/if}